# Transferring mysql database to new server

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to transfer mysql data from my old server to new server. The tables are of very large sizes(approx 1.7GB). So, its a real pain to transfer them to new server. Exporting the file as  sql file is not working.

Is there any other better and efficient method to do the same ?

Thanks !

Comment: Is the first server on Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You could simply copy the mysql folder in which the tables are, usually in locations like `/var/lib/mysql`

2) You could pipe the output of `mysqldump` to a compression program like gzip or bzip and transfer smaller files (see: http://www.ducea.com/2006/10/28/compressing-mysqldump-output/)

```
 mysqldump ...options... | gzip > outputfile.sql.gz
```

Comment: Where Can I get that mysql folder ?

Comment: I would definately go for the second option. I don't know the internals of MySQL and how it handles its directories but the first option seems risky in my view.

Comment: Try to look into `/var/lib/mysql`. 
@BlueEel Not at all, a simple copy is enough, provided you assign the right permissions, I've done it many times as backup. I prefer the gzipped dump, though.

Comment: also have a look at the official documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/copying-databases.html

Comment: @Craino No such path in my control panel

Comment: @PrashantSingh You should look with a shell, not with some "control panel". Anyway, there's always the `mysqldump` option, but requires the possibility to use a terminal, too. Do you have such a possibility? (direct access to server? or is it hosted?)

Comment: Then the only way is the "regular" SQL dump, I'm afraid. Many "control panels" give the possibility to compress the output with zip/gzip, have a look to the various possibilities

Comment: Or you could ask your hosting provider to make the dump for you and make it available for download somewhere.